# What is wrong with this assembly accessing this string constant?

Tags: assembly, nasm

I thought I was starting to understand whats going on, but I've been spending ages now trying to understand why the following doesn't work:

```
org 0x7C00

mov ax,0x0000
mov ds,ax

mov si, HelloWorld

HelloWorld db 'Hello World',13,10,0
```

What I'm expecting is that the `mov si, HelloWorld` instruction will place the value `0x7C08` in `si` (which is `0x7c00` + the offset of `HelloWorld`), ready for things like `lodsb`.

When I build this (using Nasm) and run it (using Bochs) I find up that the end instruction actually looks like this:

```
mov si, 0x8400
```

Why is this, and where has the value `0x8400` come from?

**Update:** I've discovered that placing `HelloWorld` in the data segment produces the expected output:

```
section .data
HelloWorld db 'Hello World',13,10,0
```

Why is this?

FYI the command used to build this is `nasm -f bin input.asm -o output.bin`

**Update 2** I've twigged that `0x8400` is `0x7c00 + 0x0800`, where 8 is the offset of `HelloWorld` from the beginning of the output - I noticed this when I spotted that when using `org 0` the address used is `0x0800`.

I still don't understand whats going on though - spotting this has just made me more confused!

As requested, disassembly using `ndisasm`:

```
00000000  B80000            mov ax,0x0
00000003  8ED8              mov ds,ax
00000005  BE0084            mov si,0x8400
00000008  48                dec ax
00000009  656C              gs insb
0000000B  6C                insb
0000000C  6F                outsw
0000000D  20576F            and [bx+0x6f],dl
00000010  726C              jc 0x7e
00000012  640D0A00          fs or ax,0xa
```

Comment: How do you build and run it? Here's what I see:
`mov         si,07C08`

Comment: Are you using any special flags on the nasm command line?  When I run the above code through nasm I get what you expect.

Comment: Yes, give us the full `nasm` command line needed to reproduce this.

Comment: @Aaron I'm using `nasm input.asm -f bin -o output.bin`.

Comment: The offset can be any random number depending on where the assembler puts `HelloWorld` in the memory.  Thats probably why you were getting a larger hex number

Comment: @Trefor - No.  The assembler definitely puts the string immediately after the mov instruction.  That's the way assemblers work -- they don't move stuff away from where you typed it.

Comment: @kragen - with that command I'm still getting exactly what you expect.  I'm using nasm version 2.09.08 on cygwin.  What version are you using?  Can you append a disassembly using ndisasm?

Comment: @Aaron My NASM version is `NASM version 2.09rc1 compiled on Jun  7 2010` running on Windows (no Cygwin) I've put the dissassembly in my question text.

Comment: @Aaron Just installed `2.09.08` (for some reason I thought that `2.09rc1` was the latest) and it works fine - can't believe it was something that stupid (no wonder I was confused!) Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @Kragen - that explains why Igor and I were getting different results from you. Good to hear that it's solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrade your copy of nasm.

Using nasm 2.09rc1 I get the following (unexpected) disassembly:

```
00000000  B80000            mov ax,0x0
00000003  8ED8              mov ds,ax
00000005  BE0084            mov si,0x8400
00000008  48                dec ax
00000009  656C              gs insb
0000000B  6C                insb
0000000C  6F                outsw
0000000D  20576F            and [bx+0x6f],dl
00000010  726C              jc 0x7e
00000012  640D0A00          fs or ax,0xa
```

Using nasm 2.09.08 I get the following (expected) disassembly:

```
00000000  B80000            mov ax,0x0
00000003  8ED8              mov ds,ax
00000005  BE087C            mov si,0x7c08
00000008  48                dec ax
00000009  656C              gs insb
0000000B  6C                insb
0000000C  6F                outsw
0000000D  20576F            and [bx+0x6f],dl
00000010  726C              jc 0x7e
00000012  640D0A00          fs or ax,0xa
```

I guess it was a release candidate for a reason... :)

Comment: Thanks again for the help - I now feel both a little bit smarter (now that I realise that my assembly was right all along) and really stupid for managing to install the wrong version!

Answer (score 2):

Unless you use `bin` format, nasm is allowed to move your data into a `segment .data`  This makes a lot of sense when compiling to a PE format such as .EXE.

In other words, are you certain that `0x8400` is not the proper address once the output binary has been laid out and linked?  I understand you are trying to emit data in the `segment .text` -- to do that, I think you need the `bin` directive.

Edit:

Given that you are using the `bin` format, and considering your additional information that building the `HelloWorld` string in `segment .data` does work, I suspect what you need to do is:

```
lea si, [cs:HelloWorld]
```

I may be off on the syntax -- it's been years since I coded in 16-bit x86 -- but the point is that you're getting an offset based on an assumption about the value of `ds`, which you are explicitly clearing and which the assembler might assume has the value of `segment .code` or similar.  (Thanks to Aaron for correcting my mov to an lea.)

Comment: So I'm using `-f bin`, also `0x7C08` is the actual address of the string when I'm debugging.

Comment: I believe that the syntax is `mov si, [cs:HelloWorld]`, but NASM just produces `mov si, [ds:0x8400]`, which I still don't understand.

Comment: @Kragen - I believe that that last statement moves the data at the address `[cs:HelloWorld]` into si - not the address.  To move the address of that you'd need `lea si, [cs:HelloWorld]`.  But I don't believe this is actually what you want either.

Answer (score 1):

From [MASM](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc8.html) help:

> The first object file containing code
>   should start its code segment with a
>   line like RESB  100h. This is to
>   ensure that the code begins at offset
>   100h relative to the beginning of the 
>   code segment, so that the linker or
>   converter program does not have to
>   adjust address  references within the
>   file when generating the .COM file.
>   Other assemblers use an ORG  directive
>   for this purpose, but ORG in NASM is a
>   format-specific directive to the bin
>   output  format, and does not mean the
>   same thing as it does in
>   MASM-compatible assemblers.

So, you have code segment CS and data segment DS and they are not equal, therefor also label pointers are different, depend of section.
**Under x86 the section alignment is usually 4096 bytes which fit the size of a memory page.**

Comment: But they aren't off by 0x100, they are off by 0x800 -- which is a VM page (4096 bytes) and makes me wonder if his @data is equal to his @text minus 0x800 -- giving room for a PE or MZ header on an EXE.

Comment: No, do not init manualy DS and SC (SS also) segment registers this is made before the program start. The proper CS and DS values are written in program header table. The memory space between CS and DS is defined at compile time (normaly at least one memory page). Therefor you must to use sections .text, .data and .bss

Comment: This is for a bootloader, so there is no program header table.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... 'H' is 0x48.  Maybe you're pulling the first byte of 'Hello World' instead of the address of it.

Comment: What would reverse the nibbles to 0x84?

Comment: I was thinking that as well - except then the value would be 0x4800, not 0x8400.  Also - that's a 16-bit move.

Comment: I wondered this and so tried changing the string to start with another character, but I got the same value so concluded it was just a coincidence.

Comment: Oh, right.  This is why I quit assembly language a long time ago, started to make me feel dyslexic.